# SIGINT in Visual Studio Code Integrated Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the regular windows terminal Control+C is keybound to SIGINT allowing you to break a running process. Visual Studio Code's Integrated Terminal enables you to have passthrough key commands through terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell, which is quite useful. Although Control+C is keybound to copy by default, SIGINT isn't readily apparent in the settings to set up a keybind for. How can you send SIGINT to the Visual Studio Code Integrated console, and preferably keybind it, so that you can signal processes to stop or interrupt?

Here is the documentation I was able to find, which unfortunately has no references to SIGINT or using Control+C for interrupts which I imagine is a common need: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that on Visual Studio Code for Windows, `ctrl-c` and `ctrl-v` among other commands are set to bypass the terminal and be handled by VSCode itself.

To fix simply open your preferences `File>Preferences>Settings` (`ctrl-,`) and add your own `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` settings value. It's best to let VSCode do the work for you by using it's intellisense feature so that you get all the defaults included so that you don't accidentally change other behaviour you expected to work.

Then go ahead and remove the `workbench.action.terminal.copySelection` to let `ctrl-c` work and `workbench.action.terminal.paste` to get `ctrl-v` to work.

Pasting into the terminal will still work for `ctrl-shift-v` but I haven't yet figured out how to make copying work. I'll update this answer if I do.

Comment: It turns out it is quite easy to get copying from the terminal working. Simply go into your keyboard shortcuts under `File>Preferences>Keyboard Shorcuts` and search for `terminal`. You'll see a "Copy Selection" shortcut which is set to `ctrl-c`. I changed mine to `ctrl-shift-c` to match the paste command.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to send SIGINT with another shortcut?