# How to send SIGKILL or SIGQUIT (CTRL + BACKSLASH) in VSCode terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Is there a way to configure a keyboard shortcut for VSCode terminal to send a SIGQUIT to the running process?

Sending a SIGINT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) seems possible (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45257525/1804173) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43667317/1804173) question), but that doesn't help with processes that configure a SIGINT handler and cannot be killed via SIGINT.

On the Linux machine I'm ssh-ing to I can normally use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to send a SIGQUIT in such a case. This doesn't seem to work in the VSCode terminal out-of-the box. Is there a way to manually configure a comparable keyboard shortcut?

---

Some related questions not VSCode specific:

- [List of terminal generated signals (eg Ctrl-C -> SIGINT)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362559/list-of-terminal-generated-signals-eg-ctrl-c-sigint)
- [How do you use a keyboard shortcut that requires ctrl-\ when you have to use multiple keys to type an \?](https://superuser.com/questions/506061/how-do-you-use-a-keyboard-shortcut-that-requires-ctrl-when-you-have-to-use-mul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something that works. I've added the following to the `keybindings.json` (by going to *File => Preferences => Keyboard Shortcuts*, and then clicking the small switch-to-json button in the upper right):

```js
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    // other bindings ...,
    {
        "key": "oem_4",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "\u001c"
        },
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    }
]
```

Notes:

- The `oem_4` key corresponds to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> on my keyboard, but that might be due to using German keyboard layout. The easiest way to set it is to switch back to the graphical keyboard shortcut view, search for "sendSequence", and use the keyboard shortcut detection to set the key.
- The `\u001c` was a lucky guess inspired by [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding) and [this "table"](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/0e45909c7e79c83452493d2cd46d99c0a0bb585f/src/common/data/EscapeSequences.ts#L67-L68), but it seems to send SIGQUIT properly.
- Also helpful is to run `stty -a` on the host to check if the sequence is supported by the terminal.

Comment: Some clarification, this page covers the ctrl+key mappings for terminals http://courses.cs.tau.ac.il/365-1800/05a/ASCII.html if you wanted to send the signals normally mapped to ctrl+c or ctrl+z or even ctrl+\ for that matter.